# Command line gem search tool throw error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Today I just ran into an problem. When I ran the command `gem search ^rails`,some errors appear. And I cannot figure out what is the problem. The message is:

> ➜  rubygems-2.4.5  gem search rails

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EDESTADDRREQ)
    Destination address required - send(2)

and gem -v is 2.4.5 .Then I try other command ,same error appears.

Comment: I have find the answer,because my gem sources is cannot reach ,After I change to another gem source using ` gem sources -a https://ruby.taobao.org/`.The problem does not exist.